# Problem with last / lastdb

Tags: python

I am trying to run a program called TEBreak, which detects genetic elements within a genome. However, I keep running into this warning message whenever I run it:

**Warning: could not lastdb -4G /tmp/tebreak.concat.fa.b745d57e-0363-4bab-9a48-2aebf31ffd25.fa /tmp/tebreak.concat.fa.b745d57e-0363-4bab-9a48-2aebf31ffd25.fa**

**Warning: no lastdb index for /tmp/tebreak.concat.fa.b745d57e-0363-4bab-9a48-2aebf31ffd25.fa**

What does this mean exactly, and is it a problem with the temp files, or lastdb?

The link to the python script for the program is here: https://github.com/adamewing/tebreak/blob/master/tebreak/tebreak.py

I searched the script for the error messages:

[image]

I did contact the author of the program, who suggested this:

**The lastdb problem might be due to a missing prerequisite, sorry there are several of those... try running 'lastdb' by itself to see if it's on the system.**

I have checked and lastdb is installed, but I can't find the version info - would this make a difference?

Could anyone shed some light on this error, and what I could do to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The errors occurs because ***python***'s `os.path.exists(path)` function returns `False`.

According to documentation there could 2 reasons:

> **`os.path.exists(path)`**
>
> Return `True` if path refers to an existing ***path*** or an open file descriptor. Returns `False` for broken symbolic links. On some
>   platforms, this function may return `False` if permission is not granted
>   to execute `os.stat()` on the requested file, even if the path
>   physically exists.

---

1) check if your `*.db` and `*.tis` files have consistent symbolic links

2) check read/execute permissions on the above files

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about checking the *.db and *.tis files?

Comment: if you know the exact filenames - start with searching/locating them, for ex. `find / -type f \( -name "*.db" -o -name "*.tis" \)`. If the needed files are found, check parmissions with `stat <found_filename_path>`